# Function keys for volume up/down not working after upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04LTS to 22.04LTS. After upgrade, my FN keys for volume up/down are no longer working. How to fix that ?

Comment: That may depend on the brand and type of your computer.

Comment: It is not working for me either.

Comment: Strangely as it sounds, it works now.

Comment: Not for me, even with all updates installed

Comment: Same here... I'm still trying to figure out how to fix it as it's super anoying

Comment: It seems to happen to all function keys. This has gone on long enough that I never even try to press them to change the button.